# Refetch Container with two independent data sets

Tags: relayjs, relay

I have a component that has two 'independent' datasets, in that refetching argument `a` changes field `A` and refetching argument `b` changes field `B`.

```
export default createRefetchContainer(
  Component,
  {
    a: graphql`
      fragment Comp_a on Query @argumentDefinitions(
        a: { type: "String!", defaultValue: "" },
      ) {
        A(a: $a) {
          name
        }
      }
    `,
    b: graphql`
      fragment MainList_repo on Query @argumentDefinitions(
        b: { type: "String!", defaultValue: "" }
      ) {
        B(b: $b) {
          name
        }
      }
    `
  },
  {
    a: graphql`
      query CompRefetchQuery($a: String!) {
        ...Comp_a @arguments(a: $a)
      }
    `,
    b: graphql`
      query CompRefetchQuery($b: String!) {
        ...Comp_b @arguments(b: $b)
      }
    `
  }
)
```

There is no such example in relay docs, and I just inferred this from fragment containers. The problem is calling

```
props.relay.refetch(vars => ({ data }), null)
```

results in a `RelayModernGraphQLTag: Expected an operation, got`{}`.` error (reporting refetch itself as the call site).

Is there a way to create two 'refetch' subsets like this in relay? Or do I need to create two refetch containers and nest them?